# Multiple session for multiple login without any store

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express-session

I am using **express-session** to handle session in node.js along with fabric composer for blockchain case.
This is for **development** purpose.

***Problem:***

We have  A , B organizations , if i login to A and in **same browser(another tab)** if i login to B and if the tab with A logged in is refreshed it loads the session data of B ( which is latest session ).

I want to **separate** the session between A and B in same browser between the tabs.

**I dont want to setup any store**.
I have not tried much on this i want to start well as i am working on session for first time. so it'd be helpful if i get a guidance to START, GO AHEAD WITH and SOME EXAMPLES to try out with.

I have gone through few questions related to session but most answer solves it using STORE(like separate DB, as i am working with blockchain and just for few KBs of data i dont think i want to setup entire new DB)

Thanks in adv

Answer (score 2):

**First of all:** I don't know `nodejs` so my answer is web-general.

What you want can be done without separating the databases. opening multiple sessions in the same browser can be done by not using cookies.

You can achieve that if you send the `session_id` to the browser after a successful login. This `session_id` should do the work of cookies. The browser should send it with each request (just like a cookie) and you, on the server side, make sure it makes a valid active session. I don't know if there is something for this case out of the box in nodejs.

Example URL: `http://yoursite.com/somepage?session_id=some_session_id_from_database`

**THERE IS A PROBLEM**

This way has a security flaw in it: whenever this `session_id` is stolen from the query string people can use it to "log in" to your site without valid authentication. Same as cookies but cookies are hard to steal compared to a query string. It is like putting your password in the URL. **And** You can't put it in a `POST` request because you can't make all the requests on the site of type `POST`

I hope I've answered the question. and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. this gives a bit of overview on the problem i'm facing regarding session setup.
I'm looking out specifically for express.js solution and more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the answer, but don't know the risk if any.

**WHAT I DID**

session is being created once for an application( i'm running only one app ).
first of all i have a separate router for each organization, common login route(page).

so i did session.regenarate() for every successful login so that the session after the login will be unique for that particular user.

Now, i am able to login for two different org in same browser and different tabs.

I need to test it bit more for risks or flaws..  If you guys think of any.. please comment below.